# Chart.js not reading input data

Tags: chart.js

chart.js isn't reading my data coming from a php page. I've included the console.log to show the the data is coming in. I'm a chart.js noob so any help appreciated.

If I output the data to console.log I can see the data I'm posting looks like this:

```
0
: 
"mon: 'Jan', cnt: 18"
1
: 
"mon: 'Jun', cnt: 18"
2
: 
"mon: 'Jul', cnt: 18"
3
: 
"mon: 'Aug', cnt: 18"
4
: 
"mon: 'Sep', cnt: 18"
```

My basic code is below:

````
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showGraph();
        });


        function showGraph()
        {
            {
                $.post("data.php",
                function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    var mon = [];
                    var cnt = [];

                    for (var i in data) 
                    {
                        console.log(data[i].mon);
                        mon.push(data[i].mon);
                        cnt.push(data[i].cnt);
                        //console.log(data[i].mon);
                        //console.log(data[i].cnt);
                    }

                    var chartdata = {
                        labels: mon,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Month',
                                backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                data: cnt
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");

                    var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: chartdata
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        </script> ```

Thank you for any help
````

Comment: It's not clear to the output of console.log of data.. Anyway, I have created a codepen with your code and it's working: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/wvYeKxb. Are you sure that the "data" is an array of JS objects?

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for the work on this, its still not working, I'm loading the data from a 'data.php' page as: 
$data[] = "{mon: 'Jan', cnt: $jan_count}";
$data[] = "{mon: 'Jun', cnt: $jun_count}";
$data[] = "{mon: 'Jul', cnt: $jul_count}";
$data[] = "{mon: 'Aug', cnt: $aug_count}";
$data[] = "{mon: 'Sep', cnt: $sep_count}";
I think this must be the issue, I'll keep playing with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this on the PHP side, it wasn't the way I wanted to go, but posting PHP strings as JSON wasn't working, so I amended the MYSQL and just posted
as
'''
foreach ($result as $row)
{
$data[] = $row;
}
'''
Works as required now